# How is Dataset.as()'s implicit Encoder parameter defined

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following code creates a Dataset from JSON file(DeviceData is a case class):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val devicesDS = spark.read
      .json("devices.json")
      .as[DeviceData]
```

It works, but I could not understand how the Dataset's as() method does this. [Spark's Scala API document for Dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) 's as() method is below, it has implicit parameter arg0: Encoder[U] defined:

```
def as[U](implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
    Returns a new Dataset where each record has been mapped on to the specified type...
```

But if I go to [its source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala),

```
def as[U : Encoder]: Dataset[U] = Dataset[U](sparkSession, logicalPlan)
```

It does not have this parameter. The API doc should be automatically generated from this source code. Searched around, but it's still a mystery for me. Thanks for help.

Comment: `as[U : Encoder]` is just sugar syntax for `as(implicit someRandomName: Encoder[U])` this is called **context bounds**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks! I mistook the brackets as parenthesis.